# Conditional border line according to different data in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm trying to get different border line like image below.[image]

What i've been trying were below:

1. I've selected sheet like this.
   `function myBorder() { var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'))}`

But after that, i couldn't set condition for certain data in a cell.

Even if i set the condition like below,

```
if(A1:Z=="different"){
spreadsheet.getRange(A1:Z).setBorder(true,ture,true,true,null,null)
```

It just apply border set to whole sheet.

How can i solve this problem?